# how to test component routes in own spec file

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-runner

I want to test the routes used in a component. I know that I can do this in files with .spec extensions for each class in the angular framework.

a sample code(in TypeScript):

```
import {Routes} from "@angular/router";
import {TraderPurchasesComponent} from "./detail/purchases/trader-purchases.component";
import {TraderListComponent} from "./list/trader-list.component";
import {TraderDetailComponent} from "./detail/trader-detail.component";

export const TraderRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: 'traders', component: TraderListComponent},
  {path: 'traders/detail', component: TraderDetailComponent},
  {path: 'traders/detail/:trader', component: TraderDetailComponent},
  {path: 'traders/purchases/:trader', component: TraderPurchasesComponent}
];
```

I want to do : (firstly fake make a routing and then test that)

```
import {async, TestBed} from "@angular/core/testing";
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
import {Location} from '@angular/common'
import {RouterTestingModule} from "@angular/router/testing";
import {TraderRoutes} from "./trader.routes";



describe("Trader Routes ",()=> {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(TraderRoutes)],

  });

  let router:Router = TestBed.get(Router);
  let location = TestBed.get(Location);

  router.initialNavigation();

  it('navigate to "traders" takes you to /traders', async(() => {
    router.navigate(['traders']).then(() => {
      expect(location.path()).toBe('/traders');
    });
  }));

});
```